# Firebird stored procedure always returning zero

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird, c++builder-xe2

This is my stored procedure:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_ETYPE (
    E_ID Integer,
    E_NAME Varchar(20) CHARACTER SET NONE )
RETURNS (
    NEW_ID Integer)
AS
declare variable addr varchar(20);
declare variable type smallint;
declare variable ord smallint;
declare variable cmd varchar(255);
declare variable answr varchar(255);
begin
  insert into ETYPE
  select * from ETYPE where ID=:e_id;
  select max(ID) from ETYPE into :new_id;

  update ETYPE set NAME = :e_name where ID = :new_id;
  for 
    select ADDR,REGTYPE,ORD from ETYPEREGS 
      where ETYPE_ID=:e_id
      into :addr,:type,:ord
    do
      begin
        insert into ETYPEREGS
          (ETYPE_ID,ADDR,REGTYPE,ORD)
         values
          (:new_id,:addr,:type,:ord);
      end 
  for 
    select CMD,ANSWR,ORD,REGTYPE from ETYPESPECIAL 
      where ETYPE_ID=:e_id
      into :cmd,:answr,:ord,:type
    do
      begin
        insert into ETYPESPECIAL
          (ETYPE_ID,CMD,ANSWR,ORD,REGTYPE)
         values
          (:new_id,:cmd,:answr,:ord,:type);
      end
end^
SET TERM ; ^
```

This is my code in C++:

```
StoredProc_InsertEType->ParamByName("E_ID")->AsInteger = src_id;
StoredProc_InsertEType->ParamByName("E_NAME")->AsString = _name;
try
{
 StoredProc_InsertEType->ExecProc();
 new_id = StoredProc_InsertEType->ParamByName(L"NEW_ID")->AsInteger;
}
catch(EDBEngineError & e)
{
 errors->Add(e.Message);
 return false;
}
```

Variable new_id is always zero regardless of fact that table ETYPE is not empty. When I run command `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ETYPE` from administration tool FlameRobin it returns correct number (~180). What should I do to obtain correct value of NEW_ID parameter?

Comment: Using SELECT MAX(ID) to get the highest generated ID is not a good approach in Firebird, because MVCC architecture that could give you an ID that is already taken. Use a generator instead.

Comment: What happens if you remove everything except `select max(ID) from ETYPE into :new_id;`? Does it return the value of new_id?

Comment: @Mark: I get always zero :-(.

Comment: What happens if you execute the procudure directly (eg from ISQL, or Flamerobin (eg `EXECUTE PROCEDURE INSERT_ETYPE(your parameters..)`)?

Answer (score 2):

you need to add

```
suspend;
```

in your sp

and query with

```
select * from your_sp
```

suspend explained
http://www.janus-software.com/fbmanual/manual.php?book=psql&topic=104

regards,

Comment: I need to return only one value. It seems to me that suspend keyword is used when returning array of values. Apart from it in my other stored procedures there is no need to use suspend keyword.

Comment: suspend; returns ONE row of variables defined in procedure. If you call it in a cycle (for, while) you will get "an array of values" ;)

Comment: How to define input parameters?

Comment: THANK YOU! I was tearing my hair out over this, all the examples I looked at didn't even mention `suspend` for returning a single value, only for multiple rows...